# ¿Como puedo pasar una imagen de un panel de windows forms a crystal report?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Quiero saber cómo se puede pasar una imagen de un panel a un reporte de tipo `Crystal Report`.

La imagen es un código de barras que genero yo, y ocupo pasarla al reporte, pero no logro pasar la imagen al reporte

¿Cómo puedo pasar la imagen?

Comment: Agrega tu código por favor, indicando las cosas que hayas hecho :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si el reporte estas vinculado a un DataSet tipado puedes asignarlo a un campo de esta y usarlo en el reporte

[Crystal Reports – Cargar imagen usando una capa de reportes](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com/2011/02/crystal-reports-cargar-imagen-usando.html)

En el erticulo explico como puedes hacerlo, veras que uso un xsd

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es desde codigo asignar la imagen

```
Empleados.EmpresaRow row = empleado.Empresa.NewEmpresaRow();
row.Logo = ImageHelper.ImageToByteArray(ImageHelper.ObtenerImagenLogoEmpresa());
empleado.Empresa.Rows.Add(row);
```

Se crea la row del datatable para asignarle el byte array de la imagen, por ultimo asignas el dataset tipado como source del reporte

```
report.SetDataSource(empleado);
```